# Is there a way I can show the "imaginary" negative numbers or whatever numbers are missing past the 33rd integer?

Tags: python, negative-number

```
# This is the original code beginning with the number 777 and I want to show the first 37 numbers.

def Collatz(n):
    i = 1
    while n != 1:
        print(f'{i}. {n}')
        if n & 1:
            n = 3 * n + 1
        else:
            n = n // 2
        i+=1

 
Collatz(777)
```

I want it to go past and stop at the 37th number. (which probably means that the numbers are imaginary, or negative.)

33. 2
34. ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Collatz = 777 
i = 1
while i != 38:
    print(f'{i}. {Collatz}')
    if Collatz & 1:
            Collatz = 3 * Collatz + 1
else:
    Collatz = Collatz // 2
i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no more numbers to show. The last value of `n` it displays is 2. Then the body of loop executes

```
      n = n // 2
```

which binds `n` to 1. The loop just ends then, because `n != 1` is no longer true.

If you continued anyway, it would go on to repeat 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1,  ... forever.

Comment: Well now I find it weird that I was asked to do this lol, thank you.